# how to specalize class-member function template without class specialization

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

For example, i have such code:

.h-file:

```
template <typename T1>
class Templ
{
    public:
    template <typename T>
    T foo (T t);
};
```

.cpp-file:

```
template <typename T1>
template <typename T>
T Templ<T1>::foo (T t)
{
    qDebug() << "Non-specialised template";
    return t;
}

template <>
template <>
int Templ<void>::foo (int t)
{
    qDebug() << "Specialised class template void> & method template <int>";
    return t;
}
```

if I call something like that:

```
Templ <void>t;
int i = t.foo<int>(1);
```

I will get expected "Specialised class template void> & method template " message, but if i want to call unspecialized function like that:

```
Templ <float>t;
int i = t.foo<bool>(1);
```

I will get undefied reference linker error. How do I call unspecialized function?

Also, how do I define specialized function of unspecialized class? I want to do something like

```
template <typename T1>
template <>
int Templ<T1>::foo (int t)
{
    qDebug() << "Specialised class template void> & method template <int>";
    return t;
}
```

but, obviosly, it will not compile.

Comment: Related: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: Your unspecialized version [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/511b362d6d16780a) if you define the functions in the header.

Comment: TartanLlama, thx for advise, but in that case i ougth to declare function as inline, to preserve multiple definition. Also, i suppose it is not the best practice - to move realization to .h file.